# WebAPI and WebApplication on the same port

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

We would like to create a web api that is accessed by a MVC application and a mobile application. Here's our project structure:
**Application.sln**
 - **Application.Web.csproj**
 - **Application.WebAPI.csproj**
 - **Application.Mobile.csproj**

We have configured the solution to have multiple start-up projects. But in order to access the api calls through json (and not jsonp) in Application.Web's views, we need both applications to use the same port. Is there a way to do that in Visual Studio?

If not, what would you say is the best structure for us? 
Thanks,
Safris

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Did you ever succeed safriss? I was trying to do the same thing and face the same issue..

Comment: Have you tried to deploy the webapi as a virtual folder under the website?  They will then both be on the same port.